# Como fazer algoritmo para calcular sequencia de fibonacci recursivo eficiente(não sendo exponencial)?

Tags: c, algoritmo, fibonnaci

Estou estudando recursividade, e queria encontrar uma maneira de fazer um algoritmo recursivo para sequencia de fibonacci eficiente, onde o algoritmo não seja exponencial. Como vou guardar o valor dos subproblemas?? Tava pensando em usar o vetor e e tentar guardar os subproblemas ou sei lá

```
unsigned long long fibonacci (unsigned long long n){
    int cont = n, unsigned long long fib[cont];

    if(n < 2)
        return n;
    else if(n == cont)
            return fib[cont];
    else
        fib[cont] = return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);   
}
```

Comment: Recursividade para obter eficiência parece-me um pouco incoerente. Se precisar de eficiência, por que não usa um laço de repetição simples?

Comment: é porque o exercicio pede pra ser resolvido com recursão

Answer (score 1):

A solução é justamente isso que você propôs: salvar os valores já calculados
em um vetor.  Essa técnica é conhecida como memoização (ou
[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).

Armazene o vetor de valores antigos em uma variável estática, aí você poderá
salvar os dados entre uma chamada da função e outra:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_DEPTH 512

unsigned long long fibonacci (unsigned long long n){
    static unsigned long long max_n = 1;
    static unsigned long long memo[MAX_DEPTH];

    memo[0] = 0;
    memo[1] = 1;

    if (n <= max_n)
        return memo[n];

    memo[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    max_n = n;

    return memo[n];
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%llu\n", fibonacci(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Você pode ver que a função é recursiva (`fibonacci` chama a si mesma),
mas agora você só calcula o que ainda não foi calculado.  Com isso a
complexidade fica a mesma se você executar com um laço de repetição.

Comment: Cara então eu apliquei essa solução só que o tempo é mesmo de uma recursão normal, eu comparei com uma solução iterativa que ja tinha feito e ela foi instantânea, ao contrário dessa solução, tem alguma sugestão??

Comment: Eu rodei um puramente recursivo e outro com memoização na minha máquina e vi uma diferença gritante. Tenta mudar o limite superior do loop de `10` para `100` comparando as duas versões e me diz o que você acha.